Vue click event with capture, but only if condition is met
I want to prevent the click even on child components to be fired, once a certain condition is met. I was thinking to use an event listener on the parent element with the capture flag and with stopPropagation.
I am aware that you can add modifiers to the events as described in the documentation:
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers
But I want the capture modifier only be active when a certain condition is met. Even with vanilla JS, the capture part is part of the addEventListener API. So is there another way than to just add this event listener on the fly once the condition is met or passing a prop to the children?

Use @click.capture.stop to capture and stop a click. To change the handler dynamically use a computed event handler object:
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
<script setup>

import {ref, computed, withModifiers} from 'vue';
import MyButton from './MyButton.vue';

const capture = ref(true);

function onClick(e){
  alert('parent click');
}
</script>

<template>
  <my-button :="capture ? {onClickCapture: withModifiers(onClick, ['stop'])} : {onClick}"/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="capture"/>capture</label>
</template>


thanks, where does this onClickCapture come from? I never seen this before. Anyway I simplified it for me: :="isGameOver ? { onClickCapture: onGameOverClick } : {}" and then do the ´stopPropagation´ in the handler itself as you need to pass a handler and eslint doesn't like empty methods.

@Thomas https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function#event-modifiers

Thanks again, I was serarching the Vue docs and it didn't show up and google only pointed me to react.
